# Use drush-patchfile in DDEV environment

Tags: ddev

In Drupal 7 I use

> drush-patchfile

to automatically implements patches when installing/updating module via drush. But in DDEV I don't know how to extend existing drush with drush-patchfile

As you can see on https://bitbucket.org/davereid/drush-patchfile section Installation, I need to clone the repository into

> ~/.drush

directory and that will append it to existing drush.

On another project without DDEV, I've already done that with creating new docker image file

```
FROM wodby/drupal-php:7.1

USER root
RUN mkdir -p /home/www-data/.drush && chown -R www-data:www-data /home/www-data/;
RUN cd /home/www-data/.drush && git clone https://bitbucket.org/davereid/drush-patchfile.git \
  && echo "<?php \$options['patch-file'] = '/home/www-data/patches/patches.make';" \
  > /home/www-data/.drush/drushrc.php;
USER wodby
```

But I'm not sure how to do that in DDEV container.

Do I need to create a new service based on drud/ddev-webserver or something else? 
I've read [documentation](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customization-extendibility) but not sure in what direction to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @rfay comment, here solution that works for me (and with little modification can works for other projects).

1. I've cloned [repo](https://bitbucket.org/davereid/drush-patchfile/src/master/) outside of docker container; for example, I've cloned into

   > $PROJECT_ROOT/docker/drush-patchfile
2. Create custom `drushrc.php` in the `$PROJECT_ROOT/.esenca/patches` folder (you can choose different folder)

```
<?php
# Location to the patch.make file. This should be location within docker container
$options['patch-file'] = '/var/www/html/.esenca/patches/patches.make';
```

3. Add following hooks into $PROJECT_ROOT/.ddev/config.yaml

```
hooks:
  post-start:
    # Copy drush-patchfile directory into /home/.drush
    - exec: "ln -s -t /home/.drush/ /var/www/html/docker/drush-patchfile"
    # Copy custom drushrc file.
    - exec: "ln -s -t /home/.drush/ /var/www/html/.esenca/patches/drushrc.php"
```

Final project structure should looks like

```
.
├── .ddev
│   ├── config.yaml
│   ├── docker-compose.yaml
│   ├── .gitignore
│   └── import-db
├── docker
│   ├── drush-patchfile
│   │   ├── composer.json
│   │   ├── patchfile.drush.inc
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   └── src
├── .esenca
│   └── patches
│       ├── drushrc.php
│       └── patches.make
├── public_html
│   ├── authorize.php
│   ├── CHANGELOG.txt
│   ├── COPYRIGHT.txt
│   ├── cron.php
│   ├── includes
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.php
│   ├── INSTALL.mysql.txt
│   ├── INSTALL.pgsql.txt
│   ├── install.php
│   ├── INSTALL.sqlite.txt
│   ├── INSTALL.txt
│   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   ├── MAINTAINERS.txt
│   ├── misc
│   ├── modules
│   ├── profiles
│   ├── README.txt
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── scripts
│   ├── sites
│   │   ├── all
│   │   ├── default
│   │   ├── example.sites.php
│   │   └── README.txt
│   ├── themes
│   ├── Under-Construction.gif
│   ├── update.php
│   ├── UPGRADE.txt
│   ├── web.config
│   └── xmlrpc.php
└── README.md
```

At the end start ddev envronment

```
ddev start
```

and now you can use `drush-patchfile` commands within web docker container.

Answer (score 0):

You can `ddev ssh` and then `sudo chown -R $(id -u) ~/.drush/` and then do whwatever you want in that directory (~/.drush is /home/.drush).

When you get it going and you want to do it repetitively for every start, you can encode the instructions you need using post-start hooks: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extending-commands/

Please follow up with the exact recipe you use, as it may help others. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @rfay for suggestions. I've added a detailed description in my answer. I didn't clone repo within post-start hooks (it will consume a lot of time to clone repo each time project start), but just created symbolic links within hooks. It's not so flexible solution, but it faster.